# Getting the used file name from a Properties instance

Tags: java, properties, filenames

An instance of `java.util.Properties` is passed to me which has been created using:

```
[...]
properties = new java.util.Properties();

try {
  properties.load(
    AutoProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertyFile)
  );
}
[...]
```

I was wondering how I could retrieve the file name (`propertyFile` above) from the `properties` instance? I had a glance at the API and couldn't see any easy way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file name (or path name in this case) is not stored in the `Properties` instance. In fact, you haven't even passed the name to the instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. It's not saved in the `Properties` object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get this information, as a `Properties` object is not necessarily linked to a File...

Indeed, you can populate the `Properties` in several ways:

- Load a properties file (as you did in your example).
- Populate directly this object (using `put()` method from the Hashtable class).